# How to use different filename to log stdout and stderr in different shell script files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging

Here are my script files:-

## main.sh

```
# Log stdout and stderr
log_stdout_and_stderr() {
  # Close STDOUT file descriptor
  exec 1<&-
  # Close STDERR FD
  exec 2<&-

  # Open STDOUT as $1 file for read and write.
  exec 1<>$1

  # Redirect STDERR to STDOUT
  exec 2>&1
}

Log a single line

log() {
  echo "[$(date)]: $*"
}

log_stdout_and_stderr main.log

log "Started main.sh"
log "Completed main.sh"

# call first_script
source first_script.sh
```

## first_script.sh

```
log_stdout_and_stderr first_script.log

log "Started first_script.sh"

# call second_script
source second_script.sh

log "Completed first_script.sh"
```

## second_script.sh

```
log_stdout_and_stderr second_script.log

log "Started second_script.sh"
log "Completed second_script.sh"
```

Below are my outputs logs:-

## main.log

```
Started main.sh
Completed main.sh
```

## first_script.log

```
Started first_script.sh
```

## second_script.log

```
Started second_script.sh
Completed second_script.sh
Completed first_script.sh
```

I want to log messages should be logged like below in the log files.

Expected output:-

## main.log

```
Started main.sh
Completed main.sh
```

## first_script.log

```
Started first_script.sh
Completed first_script.sh
```

## second_script.log

```
Started second_script.sh
Completed second_script.sh
```

I am calling second_script.sh file from first_script.sh. I want to store the log messages used by second_script.sh in second_script.log

How can I do it? Let me know if anyone is not clear about the question.

Comment: just add the line `log_stdout_and_stderr first_script.log` in the `first_script.sh` after this line `source second_script.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `source` in order to call the scripts from the `main` script. 
Sourcing a script means that it is parsed and executed by the current shell itself. It's as if you typed the contents of the script within the `main` script. i.e.:

The following is an equivalent when you call the `second_script.sh` within the `first_script.sh`:

**first_script.sh**

```
log_stdout_and_stderr first_script.log
log "Started first_script.sh"

# call second_script
####### second_script.sh called with sourcing #######
log_stdout_and_stderr second_script.log
log "Started second_script.sh"
log "Completed second_script.sh"
######################################################

log "Completed first_script.sh"
```

Since the script will be executed sequentially, logs will be stored according to the last called `log_stdout_and_stderr`.

In order to avoid this:

1. Modify `first_script.sh` to:

> ```
> log_stdout_and_stderr first_script.log
> log "Started first_script.sh"
>
> #call second_script
> source second_script.sh
>
> log_stdout_and_stderr first_script.log
> log "Completed first_script.sh"
> ```

2. Or call the another script from within the script using the full path to script:

> ```
> log_stdout_and_stderr first_script.log
>
> log "Started first_script.sh"
>
> # call second_script 
> /path/to/second_script.sh
>
> log "Completed first_script.sh"
> ```

This way you'll call another bash shell to execute the other script (in this case `second_script.sh`). Calling the script this way you'll need to add execution permissions to the script you're calling.

Comment: I am already using your first approach temporarily. As I am using variables in main.sh which should be used across all scripts. So I am using "source first_script.sh" to get values from main.sh in first_script.sh.

Comment: did you try both options?

Comment: I am using first option currently. I haven't tried 2nd option yet. Will 2nd option gets variables from main script to sub scirpts without need of passing them?

Comment: You would need to use `export` in order to pass the variables to different subshells. So you better go with option 1 in this case.